# iPhone signing problem: Private keys "disconnected" from developer and distribution certs

Tags: iphone, code-signing

From time to time, may iOS developers experience the problem of being unable to build their apps for deployment to a device because the Keychain seems to forget that their developer certificate is associated with their private key. Both the developer cert and the private key are present, but they don't show up "under" each other as they should.

Ditto for the distribution certificate. It can get disconnected from its private key and XCode will refuse to work.

Searching the web reveals dozens of versions of this question being asked here and elsewhere. The result is either "Hey, this morning it works!" or the thread goes dead and there's no answer. (Alternative to the former is "I rebooted and it works" or "I re-launched XCode and it works".)

The answers I previously received before were all "read Apple's exemplary and flawless documentation". Well, I've been there and I've done that. Like I said, this was all working fine and now it doesn't. Nothing changed. It does this 3-4 times per year. In the past I was one of those "I re-launched XCode and now it works" guys but this time no amount of dragging, dropping, relaunching, or re-booting will work.

I'm looking for suggestions.

Comment: I like your humour although I'm German ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is causing it for you, but I know one way to fix it. I just installed lion and went through the same thing.  I simply went to the Apple Developer portal, deleted my developer certificate, followed their tutorial (which shows up when you create a new developer certificate). This basically had me generate a new CSR (Certificate Signing Request) in KeyChain.  Uploaded the new cert, then had to go into my apps and make new dev profiles with the new certificate.

Comment: When we first started developing for iPhone the docs warned us to back up the private key for our developer cert, because if we lost it we wouldn't be able to sign updates for our app on the app store. I was afraid to regenerate the developer cert because of that. When I contacted Apple last week they sent a tech note that said in 15 pages what you said in a paragraph, and they included a note saying it won't affect being able to sign updates, since programs are identified on the app store by bundle ID (makes sense). So I'm up again. No explanation why it failed in the first place.